# Unicode Filtering Problems

Tags: java, unicode, apache-poi

I have a small Problem in Java.
I am using Apache POI to get Text from doc, pdf and docx Files.
However, its getting some weird symbols and signs that I can't seem to get filtered.
Somehow I even cant get the unicode of those Symbols.

> Web
>    G

How can I use a filter for my Strings, so that I just have the usuall symbols like (/", but still can use my german letters: "üäö"?

Comment: *"I even cant get the unicode of those Symbols"* - what do you mean you "can't"? Have you tried `(int) (string.charAt(0))`? What happens? An error? Nothing? `0`?

Comment: It is helpful to post relevant code showing what you are doing and what you have tried.